# Subtract Two IEnumrable list form each other

Tags: c#, list

I have list A like:

```
1
1
1
3
3
5
```

List B like:

```
1
1
3
```

The needed result is the subtraction of this two like:

```
1
3
5
```

How can I do that?

Comment: You should be asking about `help` with your code, not the whole code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If all you want to do is removed every element that is in b from a you can just do this.

```
foreach (int i in b)
{
    a.Remove(i);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here an extension for that:

```
public static class EnumerableSetExtensions
{
    public static IEnumerable<T> SetExcept<T>(this IEnumerable<T> source, IEnumerable<T> second, IEqualityComparer<T> comparer)
    {
        if (source == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(source));
        }

        if (second == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(second));
        }

        if (comparer == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(comparer));
        }

        var secondDict = second
            .GroupBy(
                keySelector: e => e,
                comparer: comparer)
            .ToDictionary(
                keySelector: e => e.Key,
                elementSelector: e => e.Count(),
                comparer: comparer);

        foreach (var item in source)
        {
            if (secondDict.ContainsKey(item))
            {
                var itemcount = secondDict[item] -= 1;
                if (itemcount == 0)
                {
                    secondDict.Remove(item);
                }
            }
            else
                yield return item;
        }
    }

    public static IEnumerable<T> SetExcept<T>(this IEnumerable<T> source, IEnumerable<T> second)
    {
        if (source == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(source));
        }

        if (second == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(second));
        }

        return SetExcept(source, second, EqualityComparer<T>.Default);
    }

}
```

- Sample usage

  ```
  public static void Main(string[] args)
  {
      var listA = new [] { 1, 1, 1, 3, 3, 5 };
      var listB = new [] { 1, 1, 3 };

      var listC = listA.SetExcept(listB).ToList();
      Console.WriteLine("listA: {0}", string.Join(",", listA.Select(e => e.ToString())));
      Console.WriteLine("listB: {0}", string.Join(",", listB.Select(e => e.ToString())));
      Console.WriteLine("listC: {0}", string.Join(",", listC.Select(e => e.ToString())));            
  }
  ```
- Output

  ```
  listA: 1,1,1,3,3,5
  listB: 1,1,3
  listC: 1,3,5
  ```

[.net fiddle sample](https://dotnetfiddle.net/V06CFp)